# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile User has no profile

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I am getting this error, again and again, RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile
The user has no profile. as I have created signal when any user will be created then the profile will be automatically created , it was working before but when I wrote code for an update after that this error started appearing
I got stuck at this

signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
     if created:
         profile.objects.create(user=instance)
         print('profile created')


@receiver(post_save,sender=User,)
def save_profile(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
    print('profile saved')
```

models.py

```
class profile(models.Model):
      user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      image=models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',default='media/vikash.jpg')

      def __str__(self):
          return f'{self.user.username} profile'
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):


    if request.method=='POST':
        u_form=userupdateform(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        i_form=imageupdate(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and i_form.is_valid():

            u_form.save()
            i_form.save()
            messages.success(request,'you account has been updated!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))


  else:
       u_form=userupdateform(instance=request.user)
       i_form=imageupdate(instance=request.user.profile)
       context={'u_form':u_form,'i_form':i_form}
       return render(request,'users/profile.html',context)
```

forms.py

```
class userupdateform(forms.ModelForm):
    email=forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','email']
class imageupdate(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
        model=profile
        fields=['image']
```

here are errors=[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKlpx.png)
[related error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjwnd.png)

forgive about the indentation

Comment: I don't see any errors.

Comment: now see @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: It would be better to post your errors as text, rather than inserting it as a picture.

Comment: Could the error possibly be due to you having created some users before you created the `Profile` model, in which case you might need to add profiles for them manually.